# Draw segments of a bitmap using Canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas

I have a picture (resource) that I would like to use for my application in Android. But I only want to draw specific segments of it. My initial thought is to turn it into a bitmap and specify which pixels need to be drawn and where. I tried canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, src, dst, null); but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe I am not using it right.

Just wondering if it is possible at all, and what can I use to achieve this?

Thanks!

```
src = new Rect(20,40,20,40);
dst = new Rect(20,40,20,40);

canvas.drawBitmap(background, offset, 0, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, src, dst, null);
```

I was hoping to see the area specified at src's coordinates to be drawn into the area specified by dst's coordinates, but I don't see anything, other than the background.

Comment: you were on the right path, could you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dst should be where you want to draw the image in the canvas, and the src should be the Rect you want crop from.

Comment: Thank you! I got it :) My coordinates needed some adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a format that supports an alpha channel or load the bitmap as well as a greyscale image for the alpha channel, construct an image from both and draw that. Try Java's `Graphics2D` object. [Here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html)'s an article that should get you started.

Comment: @Marcos: I thought Android was built on Java.

Comment: This is, but with an entirely different API. There's no Swing ow AWT on it. Just Android components.

Comment: I also thought Android was built on Java. Although I don't know whether Android supports Graphics2D, my answer was meant to provide a direction. From the OP's question I assume he wants to use an alpha map not just a rectangle, so the Graphics2D hint was meant to provide a direction. If Android provides similar functionality you could use that as well.